# Taylor's theorem implies existence of n+1 order derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

From my  Calculus textbook:

[image]

Usually the text is careful to make sure the description above a formula establishes all the necessary preconditions to exist for the formula to be true. I noticed here though that $f^ {(n+1)} $ is referred to, without any mention of a requirement that it exist (f being order n differentiable by itself doesn't imply n+1 differentiability). Does the continuity of all the earlier derivatives imply it or is there an unstated assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement says

> $f^{(n)}$ is differentiable

so that next derivative exists

Comment: doh, didn't read closely enough

Comment: @JosephGarvin No, you didn't. But you did try to, which is more than many students do. So a good question even though it had an easy answer.